# What are those http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php POST requests I get on my server?

Tags: http, node.js

I receive a lot of requests on my Node.js server, which I don't understand.

On the picture, there are phpMyAdmin-oriented requests, that I understand as automated testing against phpMyAdmin.

But I also have testproxy.php and http://123.249.24.233/POST_ip_port.php requests on distant servers that I can't understand. Does anyone has an explanation ?

[image: Node Logs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a malicious bot, that is trying to scan web application for security vulnerabilities.

Look at these links for more information about blocking it:

https://serverfault.com/questions/700404/huge-traffic-from-post-123-249-24-233-post-ip-port-php

https://gist.github.com/renancouto/0ad35842f1c536c1dbbe

Comment: And it happened to be the same IP. Coincidence? Anyways, thanks for this info.

Comment: What I really don't understand are the POST requests addressed to my server, but not pointing to it, I didn't know this was even possible…
Do I really need to block this traffic, knowing my Node server won't have any PHP-related problem?

Comment: It this particular case, you can leave it without further security implications for you, however it's always better to fight malicious bots, if you can.